# Splitting vector layer based on shortest distance to feature in another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting, proximity, vector-layer

I have two shapefiles of Europe. One is a highly accurate shape of the continent, the other is a map of countries in Europe in 1500, containing the names of all countries as attributes. Sadly, the second map is not as precise.

[image: The image shows the precise map in blue, the other one in red.]

I would like to split up the accurate shapefile of Europe using the fields of the second shapefile. Since the overlap is not precise, I would like to split areas of the precise shapefile by the closest distance to the fields in the second shape file. While this would not be one hundred percent correct and require some fixing, It would be correct for most areas.

Is it possible in QGIS to split up one vector layer based on the fields of another vector layer, using the shortest distance as a selection attribute?